# Drawing a graph with Graphics2D using WindowBuilder

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, windowbuilder

So I have a JPanel called *displayPane* and I want to make it a drawing area for a graph (I am making a graphing calculator). I am using WindowBuilder and this is the generated code for the JPanel:

```
JPanel displayPane = new JPanel();
displayPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
displayPane.setBounds(173, 33, 455, 432);
frame.getContentPane().add(displayPane);
```

After that I want to draw the axis of the graph but I have no idea how.
I've searched everywhere about it but everyone constructs a member class or something in the main class and adds the paintComponent(Graphics g) but that confuses me. What is that trying to accomplish ? Or just give me your way of doing it I don't really care as long as I understand it.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think that you may be coming here a bit prematurely. You'll want to start here: [Performing Custom Painting With Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), and then try some things out.

Comment: Alright, I was actually exploring WindowBuilder and it seemed easy but it seems you actually have to write some code yourself lol

Comment: Yep, Windows Builders shield you from code creation but at a cost -- you don't learn how to create code. Now it's time to roll up your sleeves and get your hands dirty with actual coding. This will require  effort, reading the tutorials, and experimenting. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions where I should start with Java GUI in general ?

Comment: Both Mad and I have given you some links. 1+ to Mad by  the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm going to give you general guidance without code, but first and foremost, please read [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) on performing custom painting with Swing. Next you should put the Window Builder software to the side and work on creating your own code from scratch, at least do this til you're comfortable coding with Swing.

Next suggestions:

- Have your DrawingPanel extend JPanel
- Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`
- Call the super's method in your override, `super.paintComponent(g)` as this will refresh the graphics and erase old "dirty" pixels.
- Play with drawing lines using g.drawLine(...)`
- keep doing this and you'll get the idea of what you'll need.

Comment: Its not homework, its just a project I started for fun, thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @ArnZXY: it's still home work -- a program you're doing at home. Makes no never mind if it's an assignment or not. The goal is to learn which can only be achieved by coding.

Answer (score 1):

Custom painting is achieved by overriding the `paintComponent` method of a `JComponent` based class (like `JPanel`).

This gives you access to the drawing surface onto which content is drawing and eventually shown on screen

See [Custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

The `Graphics` API (or more specifically, the `Graphics2D` API) is a power abstract toolkit which provides with the means to actually paint stuff to the screen.

At the basic level, this provides you with the ability to specify colors and draw basic shapes and text.  At a more complex level, you can define you own shapes, perform more complex coloring effects, including gradient fills and transformations of the basic context

See the [2D Graphics Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details.